# How to make a server function variable global to the UI in shiny

Tags: shiny

I have written the following code, please see below, but it does not work.  I get the error: Error in tag("span", list(...)) : object 'returnedParam' not found.  It is my understanding that to make a server variable global and visible by the UI, one has to define it in the global.R file.  Am I missing something?

```
    global.R
    returnedParam = null,

app.R
    ui <- fluidPanel(

    helpText(returnedParam)


    )

    app.R
    server <- function(input, output)
    output$checkedInput <- renderText({
        #inFile <- input$file
        #inFileName <- input$file$name
        result <- glycoPipe(inFileName())
        result$params
        returnedParam <- result$pass
        return(returnedParam == TRUE)
         return(result$params)
    })
```

Comment: This time I have written returnedParam = FALSE in global.R and in the ui panel I have written if(exists("returnedParam"))
    helpText(returnedParam).  And it seems that returnedParam does not exist.  However, I get the value returnedParam returned from the function and I can use it locally.  I can never get the variable in global.R to work.  Is there any thing I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean:

returnedParam = NULL

Hopefully that should fix?

Comment: I have returnedParam = NULL in global.R now but still does not work.  I also included if(exists(returnedParam)) hetlPext("returnedParam) in the UI function and I initialized the variable for testing purposes - returnedParam = "returned" in the server function and what happens is that returnedParam does not exist.  I have never been able to make the global.R variable definition work.  It seems so simple.  Do you think there is something meesing?

Comment: I solved the problem.  What happens is that to display the value of the global variable in the main panel one has to define the variable in a renderText context and use textOutput in the main panel.  Thank you for your response.